# Installing Ubuntu 22 LTS on an empty second drive, no boot managers, leave first drive INTACT

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, bootloader

HARDWARE:

- 12600KF Intel PC with a Z690 ASUS board. (Firmware updated)
- /dev/nvme0n1: Windows 11 Pro
- /dev/sda: Ubuntu 22 LTS (what I'm installing)

/dev/sda currently has OpenBSD 6.8

OBJECTIVE:

1. **NOT** dual boot. **NO** boot manager.
2. I **WANT** to manually set which drive to boot from in the BIOS each time.
3. Don't care if it's not secure boot.
4. I want / in a single partition. No separate /home partition.

After choosing "Something Else," I get a list of the partitions on each drive.

WHAT I THINK IS CORRECT:

1. Set all the /dev/nvme0n1 partitions to "do not use this partition."
2. Delete all the partitions on /dev/sda.
3. Set "Device for boot loader installation" to /dev/sda.

**QUESTION 1:**
Can I just leave /dev/sda partitionless and click continue? Will it create the necessary partitions for EFI and /?

**QUESTION 2:**
If I have to manually create the partitions on /dev/sda, which ones do I make and what size? Do I have to leave any free space at the beginning and end of the drive?

Comment: Question 1: Yes and Yes. Question 2: Moot. Of course, you may need to open the case and physically disconnect the other storage device in order to be sure you achieve Objectives #1 and #2. The installer will try to place GRUB on the boot disk regardless of which disk has Ubuntu. It's clever that way. Reconnect after the install is complete.

Comment: I may, or I MUST? I'm sure you know how much fun it would be to disassemble almost everything in the computer to reach the NVMe SSD.

Question 3: Will the "Device for boot loader installation" set to the /dev/sda be adequate or will it still try to write it to the NVMe drive?

Question 4: In the BIOS, the NVMe drive is not the boot drive, does that matter?

Trying not to dismantle anything.